# Generic C# constraint not enforced by the compiler

Tags: c#, .net, generics, unity-game-engine, generic-constraints

I am working in Unity3D (in C#), where I have this generic class defined:

```
public class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
```

This is a template for a singleton type that other classes derive from.

The *MonoBehaviour* class contains too many fields &methods, so to keep the returned Singleton instance (of type T) from being too cluttered, I have defined the following type:

```
/// <summary>
/// A singleton implementation where the Instance property can return another type I (derived from T)
/// </summary>
public class Singleton<T, I> : Singleton<T> 
    where T : MonoBehaviour, I
{
    public static new I Instance
    {
        get
        {
            // Return the Instance property, cast as I
            return (I)Singleton<T>.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

This is all good and well, however the following new type definition does not result in a compiler error:

```
public class SomeVideoProvider : Singleton<SomeVideoProvider, IVideoAds>
{
    // Why doesn't the compiler enforce this type to be derived from IVideoAds ?
}
```

The generic constraint declares that T should be both MonoBehaviour and I. In this case it is not satisfied, but there's no compiler error. Why is that ?

Comment: Well we can't see what `SomeVideoProvider` or `IVideoAds` are, which makes it very hard to tell what's going on. Please provide a short but *complete* example.

Comment: I gave the definition of SomeVideoProvider. IVideoAds is an interface that is not derived from anything else.

Comment: I just copy-pasted your code and got the expected compiler error.

Comment: @Servy where did you paste it in? I am using Unity (as stated in my question), which uses Mono, perhaps it's related to the old (buggy) compiler they use there...

Comment: I am not sure why this is downvoted. The purpose of this was to understand whether my code is valid, and if not, learn how the generic types and their constraints were misused...

Comment: Certainly appears to be a bug with Unity's fork of Mono.

Comment: @ClayFowler: I suppose that's a reasonable point; I retract my criticism.